# Allow "Mouse Click" event or "switch Excel tab" when a macro is running

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365, microfocus

I have a macro that extracts data from Microfocus RUMBA Mainframe Display and puts in Excel rows one after the other. I have created a Global Mainframe object and that is used for extraction to Excel. But when the process is running and if user decides to stop the processing he cannot click on Stop button on Excel or go to different tabs to see the data being pasted. He has to clicks like 6 times before tabs are switched or stopped.

I see that DoEvents allows mouse click events in the loop to do things but the code is written in a way that there is a lot of lines with in the loop and a function with no loop, and placing DoEvents after everyline seems irrational. I have a feeling there is a better to do that but not sure what that is. Can anyone please help?.

Comment: `DoEvents` is the only way. It's up to you to decide where to put it i.e. which statements take long to execute, a loop for example. Keep in mind that excessive use has a performance penalty.

Comment: Yes I agree. I feel like using it too many times might slower the performance. But looks like I have to go that way. Thanks Kostas

Comment: Just throw a DoEvents at a single key point in the loop. If the user clicks a cancel button, set a variable that tells the macro to stop on the next iteration. That’s how I’ve done it previously.

Comment: @skin - Thank you. I have 2 functions, 1 with loop and 1 without. I think I know where to place Doevents in the loop but not sure where to place it in a non loop function?. And also can I use multiple DoEvents in 1 function?. Lets say 3 -4?.

Comment: Yeah, you can user multiple, that's no problem and with the placement, loops are obviously easy, if you have 1000's if iterations then you just put it before or after the long running parts within the loop.  For non-looping parts of the macro, it all depends on what your macro is doing.  If you have a single line of code that runs off to a web service that takes 5 minutes to do what it does then you can't do anything about that but if you have multiple single points of long running processes then just put them in places that make sense.

Comment: It would help to create a small function that does the work and returns True if it should stop.  Call DoEvents and then check the global variable to see it has been set by the button push to Cancel.  Something along those lines anyway.

Comment: @Skin - I got it Thank you. I will go ahead and do it and let you know once it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA is single threaded. So you can't have one VBA action interrupt another. If you had a cancel button, for example, and the user was allowed to click it via a `DoEvents` processing the cancel action would still run after the currently running procedure.

In Excel this single threaded nature ends up being a good thing because you generally don't want the user interacting with the workbook while you are making programmatic changes. If this was allowed you would get undefined behavior.

Your best course of action would be to make a .NET application that uses the [Excel Interop extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects) to move the data from the mainframe to Excel. If you use VB.NET then you will find the code is quite similar to VBA. In fact, the `Excel.Application` object model is identical so the macro code you already have ports cleanly over.

There is an add-in that will help RUMBA development here:
https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/rumba/desktop951/RumbaSystemAdminGuide/GUID-DDB7571D-6167-4F8B-876E-E7450F3030B2.html

Comment: But what if user wants to stop the processing in the middle?. I would like to end the processing where it is at that moment when the stop button is clicked. Which can be allowed only with DoEvents?. Unfortunately its not upto me to decide on .NET End.

Comment: I'm telling you that your chosen path has limitations. I've shown you that if you take a different path you don't have those limitations. If it's not your decision then this is what you tell to the person makes the decisions. If you want a cancel button, you need to use a different technology. (There are tons of other amazing benefits to using the correct tool for the job. This is just the tip of the iceburg.)